# Is there an R function for sampling from 1:n across a vector of n's?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I am trying to pick one random value between 1 and `n`, given a vector of `n`'s. This is my current solution:

```
n <- c(10, 5, 35, 16, 2)
sapply(n, function (x) sample(seq_len(x), 1))
```

However, this seems like an inefficient solution because I am looping over `n` and sampling from 1:n every time. Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: Try this maybe? `sapply(n, function(x) sample.int(x, 1))` - You're still looping over n but you don't have to feed in a vector 1:n every time (assuming you only want integers)

Comment: Or `ceiling(n * runif(n))` doesn't require a loop at all

Comment: @AndrewGustar please post your comment (and a demonstration) as n answer.

Comment: @AndrewGustar worth adding that this is due to a freaky bit of `runif` whereby it uses the **length** of `n` rather than any **value** of `n` when it's a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without a loop with

```
ceiling(n * runif(n))
```

According to the documentation, if `n` is a vector, `runif(n)` is treated as `runif(length(n))`.

Comment: You can try `round(runif(n, 1, n))` as well

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding  but that will produce the occasional zero value. OP asked for 1 to n

Comment: @CarlWitthoft isn't `runif(n,1,n)` giving real numbers between `1:n[1]`, `1:n[2]`, ..., `1:n[length(n))`? `runif` is vectorized indeed.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding  oops, yes you are correct.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this question is marred by a failure to specify whether you want the distribution or sample set to be discrete. Your solution suggests you want it to be discrete, but the request for a single random value between 1 and n would be:

```
 runif(1, 1, n)
```

... whereas the request for a "random value" from the discrete space: 1:n, would be

```
 sample( 1:n, 1)
```

Your solution for the second possibility appears sensible. If you found by way of testing that the `sample` function was somehow "slowing you down" then you could first find the maximum of `n` and then create a single vector of random values form 1:nmax and then use runif with round or ceiling to draw from items less then the n's but that seems destined to be less efficient. Maybe not, programmers are often lured into hours-long investigations that are not really necessary, just to satisfy some claim of superior efficiency.